# Find the Directory of folder in root from a aspx page which is inside a folder in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a aspx page to upload image to a folder.The aspx page is inside a folder called admin.
If i keep the aspx page in the root directory i am able to upload file in the Image folder since both are in the root directory.

But when i do the same keeping the aspx page inside a folder,it shows `Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\...`

So how do i provide path such that i am able to upload image in a folder from a page which is also inside a folder.

Here goes my code:

```
      if( fu_subcat.PostedFile.ContentLength>0 )
        {
          fn =Path.GetFileName(fu_subcat.PostedFile.FileName);
            fu_subcat.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("imag/" + fn));
        }
```

**EDIT**

It is mapping the path as:
`Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\lenovo\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\emarket\Admin\imag`

But i have the folder inside emarket as `emarket\imag` not `emarket\Admin\imag`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because when you call that code from

/Admin/page.aspx

Server.MapPath returns a path which is relative to /Admin/ - so the final path would be /Admin/imag/... To set path from the root you should add a / in front of the path.

Must be

```
fu_subcat.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("/imag/" + fn));
```

Notice / in front of the string.

Alternatively you can also add a ~ tilde

```
fu_subcat.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/imag/" + fn));
```

which points to a root of the current ASP.net application. This will be useful if you application is running in a virtual directory and as a part of global application.

Answer (score 1):

Best to keep the image in a separate content folder, and then reference the image in a relative path, using the tilda e.g ~"content/image"

Comment: content folder?? What is this?? I have a different folder to keep image but i dint know what is content folder..please explain a bit.

Comment: Ok that is fine, using the tilda was my main point, because you want a relative path e.g "~/image/" will find the path depending on where your project is configured to.

Answer (score 1):

Using ~ will get you to the virtual root of your application, so Server.MapPath("~/imag/...") should do it.